# pyspark - Check if shuffle caused when joining 2 DFs repartitioned on same column

Tags: join, pyspark, shuffle

- Spark Version: 2.4.7
- `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)` is set

I have two pyspark dataframes which I want to co-partition and hence avoid shuffling. I tried to
repartition them, giving same number of partitions and same column for repartitioning, and wrote as
parquet files. Now I'm trying to check if a shuffle is actually happenning or not when I subsequently
use these tables.

**Stats on initial dataframes**

```py
>>> initital_df1.count(), initial_df1.select('id').distinct().count()  # distinct rows per id
(1000, 1000)
>>> initital_df2.count(), initial_df2.select('id').distinct().count()  # 300 rows per id (25 yrs of data, 1 row for each month)
(300000, 1000)
>>> initial_df1.rdd.getNumPartitions(), initial_df2.rdd.getNumPartitions()
(2, 8)
>>> initial_df1.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
[500, 500]
>>> initial_df2.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
[56400, 50700, 45000, 40800, 36300, 30000, 25200, 15600]
```

**Step 1: repartition the initital dataframes with same number of partitions and same partitioner column**

```py
>>> initial_df1.repartition(4, 'id').write.parquet(df1_write_path)
>>> initial_df2.repartition(4, 'id').write.parquet(df2_write_path)
```

**Step 2: read the previously repartitioned dataframes at a later point of time to perform some computation**

```py
>>> repartitioned_df1 = spark.read.parquet(df1_write_path)
>>> repartitioned_df2 = spark.read.parquet(df2_write_path)
```

**Stats on repartitioned dataframes**

```py
>>> repartitioned_df1.rdd.getNumPartitions(), repartitioned_df2.rdd.getNumPartitions()
(4, 4)
>>> initial_df1.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
[279, 255, 238, 228]
>>> initial_df2.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
[83700, 76500, 71400, 68400]
```

**Step 3: join the repartitioned dataframes read above to perform aggregations and write the aggregated dataframe**

```py
>>> agg_df = repartitioned_df1.join(repartitioned_df2, 'id').groupBy('id').agg(F.sum(col1_df1), F.avg(col1_df2))
>>> agg_df.write.parquet(agg_df_write_path)
```

Tested two scenarios:

1. `repartitioned_df1` and `repartitioned_df2` are used in step (3)
2. `initial_df1` and `initial_df2` are used in step (3)

Observarions:

1. `agg_df.explain()` gives the same spark plan in both the cases
2. Shuffle `read` and `write` data in SparkUI shows the same set of values for both cases
3. scenario (1) is at least 2x faster than scenario (2)

**Question**: How do I check if a shuffle is being caused (i.e. the dataframes are hash partitioned again) or the initial repartitioning caused the two dataframes to be co-partitioned and hence there would just be movement of partitions already created during initial writing step?